# Enviar input decimal vacio

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

Tengo el siguiente modelo. Fue generado desde la base de datos con entity.
Los dos campos pueden ser nulos.

```
public partial class Items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> largo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ancho { get; set; }
}
```

En mi vista estoy usando JqueryValidation.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.largo, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
       @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.largo, new { @class = "form-control mul" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.largo)
    </div>       
</div>

<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.ancho, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ancho, new { @class = "form-control mul" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ancho)
    </div>
</div>
```

Intento enviar el formulario sin nada en los inputs, pero no me deja por la validación de jquery (supongo)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de poder enviar los campos nulos?.

Comment: Acabo de hacer una prueba con MVC5, jQuery 1.10.2, jQuery Validation 1.11.1 y Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 3.2.3, y me funciona perfectamente. Al dejar el campo vacío me deja enviar y recibe valor null en el controlador.

Comment: Que raro, ami no me deja, voy a probar con las versiones que mencionas. ! Y ya comento, @AsierVillanueva

Comment: es raro que marque el mensaje de requerido cuando no defines las propiedades con el atributo [Required] en las propiedades de esa clase que usas de modelo. Que pasa si usas una clase diferentes a la de EF genera como modelo de esa view?

Comment: @AsierVillanueva y si acabo de probar creando un nuevo proyecto, creando mi modelo con entity y haciendo scaffolding y no tira el error, ¿Ahora, cual sera mi problema?

Comment: Es difícil decirlo. Ten en cuenta que es una clase parcial, es decir, tendrás en otro lugar la definición de la clase que puede tener diferentes atributos.

Comment: He borrado la clase partial y trabajado directamente con la que generó entity pero sigue igual ....

Comment: Y ¿cómo está definida la que generó Entity Framework? ¿Las propiedades están decoradas con algún tipo de atributo?

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Ya encontré cual era el problema, me toco desactivar script por script y fue el de globalize. Ahora veo como soluciono ese problema,

Comment: @Norcarde si has encontrado solución, agradecería que la publiques, así ayudas a mantener la salud del sitio y colaboras con la comunidad de StackOverflow En Español :D

Comment: @fredyfx la única solución que encontré en su momento, fue cambiando el tipo de dato, de **decimal** a **double**, pero creo que no es la mejor, igual entregue mi tarea así.

Comment: entonces, podrías agregar eso como respuesta y aceptarla por favor :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public partial class Items
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> largo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> ancho { get; set; }
}
```

Una solución fue cambiar el tipo de dato, de decimal a double.

Answer (score -1):

prueba quitando estas lineas : @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.largo)

Comment: Solo me quita el mensaje, pero sigue marcando error.